# ng-multiselect-dropdown not showing proper result after search

Tags: angularjs

For filter i had added below code

```
$scope.startsWith = function (actual, expected) {
    var lowerStr = (actual + "").toLowerCase();
    return lowerStr.indexOf(expected.toLowerCase()) === 0;
}
```

```
<li role="presentation"
    ng-repeat="option in options | filter: searchFilter:startsWith">
```

This will display search up to "drop down unique option " but if i had add  "drop down unique option with" than no result found in dropdown

[image: Screenshot DropDownList]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are trying for exact match, which is not good idea. You should be able to search any word like "unique option with" which is not starting from 0.

change return statement with below

```
return lowerStr.indexOf(expected.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
```

And regarding your original question, i dont find anything wrong as it should work

```js
var isTrue = "Drop Down Unique Option With Other 1022".toLowerCase().indexOf("drop down unique option with") >= 0

console.log(isTrue);
```

Comment: No that does not work. it will give same result as above. I think for search filter there is some limit.

Comment: @A.patel can you show your code with your custom **searchFilter** and  your options as well

Comment: In angularjs-dropdown-multiselect directory added below code for search filter from start with

      $scope.searchFilter = $scope.searchFilter || '';
                $scope.startsWith = function (actual, expected) {
                    var lowerStr = (actual + "").toLowerCase();
                    return lowerStr.indexOf(expected.toLowerCase()) >= 0
                }

<li role="presentation" ng-repeat="option in options | filter: searchFilter:startsWith">

Options
Drop Down Unique Option  With Other 1001
Drop Down Unique Option  With Other 1002

Comment: @A.patel Is it worked?? I dont understand the code. Who calls startWith method?? You are using filter inbuilt angular filter. Its very easy to use ` ng-repeat="option in options | filter: yourQuery">` now yourQuery is string which you put in input box to search for.